# jQuery Keybindings Not Working When Clicking Inside of iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, key-bindings

I have a few keyboard events bound the the arrow keys in jQuery. These function correctly until a user clicks inside of an iframe (which is a live video feed from ustream). At this point, none of the events fire until the user clicks on an element out of the iframe. Is there a way to force the events to fire no matter where the user clicks?

I tried putting a 100% width and height div over the top of the frame and setting it to .01 opacity, but this disallowed users to close ads on the video, which is an undesirable effect.

Link is here: http://josephndenton.com/robotdraw/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that in order to do any jquery stuff in an iframe you need to use the contents method.

So for instance:

```
<iframe id="iframe1"><div id="div1"></div></iframe>

$("#iframe1").contents().find("#div1").keyup(function(e)
{ //do your stuff });
```